# Load an image from URL with UIActivityIndicatorView on UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview, nsurlconnection, nsxmlparser

In my iphone application, I have a UITabelview which populates the data through URL. When I select one cell from UITableview, it calls the URL and downloads the image and pass on to another UITableview. When I click the cell it takes a while to load the image and stays clicked on UITableviewcell. I have the following code which calls the URL and loads the image on each cell call.

```
if (!cell) {
      cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"imageCell"] autorelease];
      imageView1 = [[cell subviews] lastObject];
      [cell addSubview:imageView1 ];
}

NSString fileName = image.Img;
NSString *filePath= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.abc.com/xml/id=12345",fileName];

UIImage *im = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]]];
subview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120.0f, 10.0f,60.0f, 60.0f)]  ;
[subview setImage:im]; 
[subview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
[cell.contentView addSubview:subview];
```

I have seen few apps where the profile pic is getting downloaded and have UIActivityIndicator loading in the data for it. I would like to use UIActivityIndicator on UIImageView in the same way. Can anyone help me out on achieving uiactivityindicator on uiimageview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.google.ru/search?q=iphone+load+image+asynchronously

Comment: Thanks for the search. But I have one more concern that once the data is downloaded, how should I display it on the detail view controller page. I have used the logic behind this code: https://github.com/slatvick/Alterplay-iPhone-dev-tips/blob/gh-pages/AsyncImage/AsynchronousImageView.m